# How to prevent bash command substitution output from being escaped?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I am trying to use command substitution in a bash script to output redirection symbols based on a variable like so:

```
IS_VERBOSE=false
curl $BLAH $( $IS_VERBOSE && echo '-i' || echo '> /dev/null' )
```

That is, if verbose, add the `-i` switch, otherwise, throw everything from stdout away.  The problem is that when `IS_VERBOSE` is false, my command becomes

```
curl $BLAH \> /dev/null
```

More generally, command substitution escapes the characters `> >> & | # $` and possibly others.  How can I output these symbols without escaping using command substitution?

Comment: I suppose all the commands are being run in a script and not an interactive shell, right? Also, what shell are you using? Is that bash or something else?

Comment: The commands are being run in a script.  I am using GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14).  I am seeing the same behavior at an interactive zsh, that is `$(echo ">")`<tab> is replaced with `\>`.

Comment: you may need to re-evaluate your expression to perform the redirection. i.e. `eval curl $BLAH $( $IS_VERBOSE && echo '-i' || echo '> /dev/null' )`

Comment: Is `$IS_VERBOSE` a command? You are treating it as one.

Comment: $IS_VERBOSE is a variable.  I will edit to show how it's set.

Comment: @adonis reevaluating does work, but I must admit I don't know why.  I'm not a fan of this solution, but it gets the job done.  Maybe add it as an answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the substition happens (which BTW in POSIX could only target the left side before any ">") there is no more evaluation on whether there is any ">" so the approach you envisioned wouldn't work.

If you don't care about POSIX-conformity (after all you tagged this as 'bash') you could still find a solution by dynamically setting the right side but I would personally go for a totally different approach; have a look at the following post detailing a verbose/silent mode based on custom file descriptors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20942015/2261442.

A code excerpt from that post to show how nice it would then look like:

```sh
# Some confirmations:
printf "%s\n" "This message is seen at verbosity level 3 and above." >&3
printf "%s\n" "This message is seen at verbosity level 4 and above." >&4
printf "%s\n" "This message is seen at verbosity level 5 and above." >&5
```

Comment: This is beautiful!  I've always wondered how scripts handled multiple verbosity levels; I'm definitely going to start working this into future scripts.  Also, you've answered the question with "there is no more evaluation" on redirects after substitution, so even if I could get it output "unescaped", it wouldn't be evaluated as I expect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't solving your escaping problem (which I'm not sure yet is possible), but coming from **man curl**, this would achieve what you're trying to do:

```
BLAH=localhost

IS_VERBOSE=true
OPTIONS="-o /dev/null"
$IS_VERBOSE && OPTIONS=""

curl $BLAH -s $OPTIONS
    <html>
    <p>hi</p>
    </html>

IS_VERBOSE=false
OPTIONS="-o /dev/null"
$IS_VERBOSE && OPTIONS="-i"

curl $BLAH -s $OPTIONS
```

The latter outputs nothing. And is less dependent on different shells (bash, sh, etc), so more portable.

Comment: Good catch.  I'd forgotten about the -o switch since a redirect is the more ubiquitous approach to saving output to a file.  This is the solution I'm going with for now.

Answer (score 2):

according to bash manual the order of shell expansions is *brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable  expansion,  command  substitution, arithmetic expansion, word splitting, and pathname expansion*. also it is stated that the redirections happen before the command is executes - i.e. after shell expansion. Thus it comes to reason that commands like:

```
redir='>'
echo value $redir file
```

and

```
echo value $(echo '>') file
```

would put *value* in the file *file*.

Unfortunately this is not the case because the command line is firstly parsed and the redirection tokens are *only* identified at this stage. Later, before the command is executed, the redirections are performed based on those tokens.

`eval curl $BLAH $( $IS_VERBOSE && echo '-i' || echo '> /dev/null' )`

works by re-parsing the command, thus identifies the redirections, but it also performs shell's expansion, which is a bit tricky to work with, and may lead in unexpected behavior.

*note:* there is special handling in bash for `>$var` and `>&$var`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now.  The redirect tokens generated after the command is parsed don't mean anything special.  I won't try to make that mistake again.  Thanks for this answer!  I feel I have a better understanding of what's going on now (as well as an obscure use-case for the evil `eval` comand.